# Using Map as a @RequestBody in Spring Boot Rest API is not working

Tags: spring-boot, rest, jackson, hashmap, jackson-databind

I want retrieve a custom json object from client for which I am reading post body using a map. But when I try to hit the API I am getting `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.util.Map.<init>()`. I am pretty sure it should work as I have written similar APIs in my previous projects. I have cross checked again by running that project again. Can someone help me what I am missing here. If any work-around solution to read the custom JSON object that is also welcome.

I have added the following dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

API Code:

```
    @PostMapping("/data")
    public ResponseEntity<Map> postInfo(@RequestBody Map input) {
        
        System.out.println("Input data: "+input);
        
        Map response = new HashMap<>();
        response.put("message", "input received");
        
        return new ResponseEntity<Map>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Postman :
[image]

console log:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.util.Map.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:216) ~[spring-web-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:139) ~[spring-web-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121) ~[spring-web-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:167) ~[spring-web-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134) ~[spring-web-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:4.0.FR]
```

And also, I changed Map to HashMap as below. This time there are no errors thrown but the input map is empty even though I am passing input Object. I am not able to get the post body.

```
    @PostMapping("/data")
    public ResponseEntity<Map> postInfo(@RequestBody HashMap input) {
        
        System.out.println("Input data: "+input);
        
        Map response = new HashMap<>();
        response.put("message", "input received");
        
        return new ResponseEntity<Map>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Postman :
[image]

console log:

```
Input data: {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may sound silly, but you can check if the RequestBody is actually being imported. It should look like this:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
```

I was facing the same issue and adding this import did the trick.

Comment: I also figured out the issue. But didn't update the answer

Comment: for other people that ended up here that might be using Swagger. make sure you import the spring request body class above and not `io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody`.

Answer (score 2):

You need the specify the types of Map object according to your case, for example Map<String, String>

```
@PostMapping("/data")
public ResponseEntity<Map> postInfo(@RequestBody Map<String, String> input) {
    
    System.out.println("Input data: "+input);
    
    Map response = new HashMap<>();
    response.put("message", "input received");
    
    return new ResponseEntity<Map>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: without type also it works. Also I have tried with types. It is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a generic collection/container without specifying their types (wildcard) when binding request body.

For example:

```
Map<String, Object>, List<Object>, Vector<Object>
```

also, if you're binding the key or value to a custom object type (which might be a third party type instead of your own), Spring need to be able to serialize/deserialize it correctly.

This means you might need to create a custom serializer/deserializer, or if the third party provides one, to correctly set it up.

Answer (score -1):

I created spring boot web project with version '2.2.2.RELEASE' to get same version spring web jar. I am able to read json using map with out any issues.

I observed one thing is in my local HandlerMethodArgumentResolver is selected as "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.**RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor**@602cf534"

but based on your exception it's selected as "org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(**ModelAttributeMethodProcessor**.java:139)
"

postman-screenshot:

[image: postman-screenshot]

eclipse-screenshot:

[image: eclipse-screenshot]

Answer (score -2):

use `@requestParam`

```
 @PostMapping("/data")
public ResponseEntity<Map> postInfo(@requestParam HashMap input) {
    
    System.out.println("Input data: "+input);
    
    Map response = new HashMap<>();
    response.put("message", "input received");
    
    return new ResponseEntity<Map>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: Adding @RequestParam defeats the purpose. My requirement is to send the data as Request body.